# TypeScript namespaces to be discontinued?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Recently, I read a quite a bit from developers who suggest not to use namespaces any more but switching to modern module handling. I'm teaching programming to beginners using TypeScript and namespaces are very valuable here, since folks can work on multiple assignments over a longer period of time in a single directory and subdirectories, without having to deal with multiple compiler configuration files and module exports and imports. They just define a namespace for a task and use that across the files they create for it.

So my question is: are there plans to discontinue namespaces in TypeScript?

Comment: Question seems off-topic. Also, modules really are not that complicated and do not require multiple configurations.

Comment: Namespaces and modules fundamentally resolve the same problem of separating code into discrete chunks. I'm not sure I really see any benefit a namespace has over a module. You do the same thing in both cases anyway - you have to create the namespace/module, then reference/import it which will allow you to use the items within. Instead of `/// <reference path="dir/Utils.ts" />` you have to put `import * as Utils from './dir/Utils'` and then `Utils.foo()` works the same. The modules are the way forward anyway, so I don't see value in not teaching students about them.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: are there plans to discontinue namespaces in TypeScript?

Probably not. Here is a comment of a Microsoft staff about another subject but it seems it is a general remark:

> This is not the TS team position. we have no plans of deprecating any thing any time soon.
> ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9950#issuecomment-300850221))

Anyway, the ES6 module system is the way to go. I suggest [an article from Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) on how to import a module as a namespace:

> When you `import *`, what’s imported is a *module namespace object*. Its properties are the module’s exports.

Comment: I wrote a little article about using namespaces and modules together. Maybe it's helpful or interesting for somebody:
https://jirkadelloro.github.io/TS-Namespaces-ES-Modules/